# Sometimes getting null pointer exception while executing async post request

Tags: java, android, post, asynchronous, forceclose

I have a login activity, the activity shows news updates on the top. To show the news updates, in the onCreate method of the activity, I am asynchronously posting to an url to get the XML for the news. Everything is working fine, but sometimes, the marquee is giving me a null pointer exception.

**The code of the activity**:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Button login;

    EditText txtUsername;
    EditText txtPassword;

    //variables to send post request
    String responseBody;
    String responseCode;
    //Progressbar object
    ProgressDialog progress;

    //checkbox obj
    CheckBox remember_me;

    //not a member textview
    TextView notMember;
    TextView otpRegister;

    //String marquee
    String marqueeHtml;

    //variables to send post request for marquee
        String marqueeResponseBody;
        String marqueeResponseCode;

        String marqueeContent;
        String marqueeToDisplay="";
        TextView marqueeTextView;
        // Exam list XML node keys
                static final String KEY_NEWS = "News"; // parent node
                static final String KEY_COLOR = "color";
                static final String KEY_TEXT = "text";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
         //setting icon to title bar
        getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.ic_launcher);

      //===============For marquee place holder===================================

        marqueeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marquee_textView);
        marqueeTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Welcome"));
        marqueeTextView.setSelected(true);
        //===============For marquee===================================

        isOnline_marquee();


        //Putting first part of URL in preferences-------------------------------------------------------------
         SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
         //Hosted url
         editor.putString("URLFirstPart","http://203.153.37.13:89/AndroidService.asmx/");
         editor.commit();
         //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

         txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
         txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

            remember_me=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.remember_me_checkBox);


            //getting user id and password from preference
            String remember_user= preferences.getString("remember_user","");
            String remember_password=preferences.getString("remember_password","");

            //setting username and password to text box
            txtUsername.setText(remember_user);
            txtPassword.setText(remember_password);

        // onclick login button
                login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
                login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        //checking whether there are values in the textboxes


                        String userId = txtUsername.getText().toString();
                        String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
                        if (userId.trim().length() == 0
                                || password.trim().length() == 0) {

                            create_alert("Warning","Please enter your userID and Password");

                        }

                        //if credentials match then forwarding to take a test activity
                        else
                        {
                            if (remember_me.isChecked())
                            {
                                saveInPreference("remember_user", txtUsername.getText().toString());
                                saveInPreference("remember_password", txtPassword.getText().toString());
                            }

                            //checking internet connectivity before sending login request
                            isOnline();
                        }
                    }
                });

        saveInPreference("showTab", "Exam");


        // onclick not member textview
        notMember = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.not_member_textView);
        notMember.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //going to next register activity       
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                finish();
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // onclick not OTP textview
        otpRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.otp_reg_textView);
        otpRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //going to next otp register activity       
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, OtpRegisterActivity.class);
                        finish();
                        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
    }

     @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // do something on back.

            twoButtonAlert("Please Note", "Sure you want to quit application?", "Yes", "No");
            return;
        }

    //check connection
    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

            //starting the progress bar
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait", "Logging in", true);

            //sending request for login
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(txtUsername.getText().toString(),txtPassword.getText().toString());



            return true;
        }

      //alert box to show internet connection error
        AlertDialog.Builder Internet_Alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
        // set title
        Internet_Alert.setCancelable(false);
        Internet_Alert.setTitle("Attention!");
        Internet_Alert.setMessage("This application requires internet connectivity, no internet connection detected");
        Internet_Alert.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                onQuitPressed(); 
            }
        });

        Internet_Alert.create().show();
        return false;
    }



    //to remove application from task manager
            public void onQuitPressed() {

                int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
            }



    //to create alert message
    public void create_alert(String title, String message)
    {
         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);

         // Setting Dialog Title
         alertDialog.setTitle(title);

         // Setting Dialog Message
         alertDialog.setMessage(message);


         // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
         alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                 dialog.cancel();

             }
         });
     // Showing Alert Message
         alertDialog.show();
    }




        //method to show toast message
        public void makeAToast(String str) {
            //yet to implement
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }


        //===================================================================================================================================
                //sending EmailAddress and Password to server
                //===================================================================================================================================
                private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{


                    @Override
                    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        postData(params[0],params[1]);
                        return null;
                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){


                        if(responseBody.contains("TRUE"))
                        {
                            String raw=responseBody;
                            raw = raw.substring(0, raw.lastIndexOf("<"));
                            raw = raw.substring(raw.lastIndexOf(">") + 1, raw.length());
                            String [] contents = raw.split(",");
                            //extracting user name and user id from response
                                String user_name=contents[1];
                                String student_code=contents[2];
                              //save user name and user id in preference
                                saveInPreference("user_name",user_name);
                                saveInPreference("student_code",student_code);

                        //login is successful, going to next activity       
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TakeTestActivity.class);
                        //hiding progress bar
                        progress.dismiss();
                        finish();
                        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            //hiding progress bar
                            progress.dismiss();
                            create_alert("Attention!", "Please provide valid userid and password");
                        }
                    }

                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){

                    }

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    public void postData(String emailId,String passwrd) {

                        //to handle connection timeout
                        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);

                        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);


                        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

                        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
                          final String url_first = preferences.getString("URLFirstPart","");
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_first+"ValidateLogin");

                        try {
                            // Data that I am sending
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EmailId", emailId));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", passwrd));
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


                                try 
                             {
                             // Execute HTTP Post Request
                             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                             //getting response body and code from the server
                             responseCode=""+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                             responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                             } 
                               catch (SocketTimeoutException ex)
                               {
                                   //showing alert in case of connection timeout
                                   AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();

                                  // Setting Dialog Title
                                  alertDialog.setTitle("Please Note");

                                 // Setting Dialog Message
                                 alertDialog.setMessage("Connection problem, please try later!");

                                 // Setting OK Button
                                 alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                                   dialog.cancel();
                                   }
                           });

                           // Showing Alert Message
                           alertDialog.show();
                               }


                            Log.d("Login response body: ", responseBody);
                            Log.d("Login response code: ", responseCode);
                        } 
                        catch (Throwable t ) {

                        } 
                    }
                }
                //===================================================================================================================================
                //END sending EmailAddress and Password to server 
                //===================================================================================================================================

                //method to save variable in preference
                public void saveInPreference(String name, String content)
                {
                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                     editor.putString(name,content);
                     editor.commit();
                }

                //method to show double button alert dialog
                public void twoButtonAlert(String title, String message, String button1, String button2)
                {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);

                    // Setting Dialog Title
                    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

                    // Setting Dialog Message
                    alertDialog.setMessage(message);



                    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(button1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                        // Write your code here to invoke YES event

                            finish();



                        }
                    });

                    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(button2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // Showing Alert Message
                    alertDialog.show();

                }


                //getting content from preferences
                public String getFromPreference(String variable_name)
                {
                    String preference_return;
                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                    preference_return = preferences.getString(variable_name,"");

                    return preference_return;
                }


              //check connection for marquee
                public boolean isOnline_marquee() {
                    ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {



                        //sending request for login
                        new MyAsyncTask_marquee().execute();



                        return true;
                    }

                  //alert box to show internet connection error
                    AlertDialog.Builder Internet_Alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                    // set title
                    Internet_Alert.setCancelable(false);
                    Internet_Alert.setTitle("Attention!");
                    Internet_Alert.setMessage("This application requires internet connectivity, no internet connection detected");
                    Internet_Alert.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            onQuitPressed(); 
                        }
                    });

                    Internet_Alert.create().show();
                    return false;
                }

                //===================================================================================================================================
                //sending request for marquee to server
                //===================================================================================================================================
                private class MyAsyncTask_marquee extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{


                    @Override
                    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        postData();
                        return null;
                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){

                        marqueeContent=marqueeResponseBody;

                        parse_MarqueeContent();

                    }

                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){

                    }

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    public void postData() {

                        //to handle connection timeout
                        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);

                        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);


                        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

                        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
                          final String url_first = preferences.getString("URLFirstPart","");
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_first+"NewsScroller");

                        try {
                            // Data that I am sending
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


                                try 
                             {
                             // Execute HTTP Post Request
                             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                             //getting response body and code from the server
                             marqueeResponseCode=""+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                             marqueeResponseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                             } 
                               catch (SocketTimeoutException ex)
                               {
                                   //showing alert in case of connection timeout
                                   AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();

                                  // Setting Dialog Title
                                  alertDialog.setTitle("Please Note");

                                 // Setting Dialog Message
                                 alertDialog.setMessage("Connection problem, please try later!");

                                 // Setting OK Button
                                 alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                                   dialog.cancel();
                                   }
                           });

                           // Showing Alert Message
                           alertDialog.show();
                               }


                            Log.d("Marquee response body: ", marqueeResponseBody);
                            Log.d("Marquee response code: ", marqueeResponseCode);
                        } 
                        catch (Throwable t ) {

                        } 
                    }
                }
                //===================================================================================================================================
                //END sending request for marquee to server 
                //===================================================================================================================================

                // function to populate marquee from xml
                void parse_MarqueeContent()
                {

                    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(marqueeContent); // getting DOM element

                    //list object to populate spinner
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_NEWS);

                    // looping through all item nodes <item>
                    for ( int i = 0; i < nl.getLength();i++) { 
                        // creating new HashMap
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                        String color=parser.getValue(e, KEY_COLOR);
                        String text=parser.getValue(e, KEY_TEXT);

                        marqueeToDisplay=marqueeToDisplay+"<font color="+color+">"+text+"</font>";
                    }

                    //===============For marquee===================================
                    saveInPreference("marquee_Html_content", marqueeToDisplay);
                    marqueeTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(marqueeToDisplay));
                    marqueeTextView.setSelected(true);
                    //===============For marquee===================================


                }
}
```

**The screen shot of the activity when its working normally:**

[image: Login Screen]

**In the top part of the activity, the Marquee is shown.**

**The logcat report when the post request fails:**

```
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:47)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at com.ica.commons.XMLParser.getDomElement(XMLParser.java:72)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at com.ica.bankpoexamination2.LoginActivity.parse_MarqueeContent(LoginActivity.java:623)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at com.ica.bankpoexamination2.LoginActivity$MyAsyncTask_marquee.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:539)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at com.ica.bankpoexamination2.LoginActivity$MyAsyncTask_marquee.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:1)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-26 04:56:11.663: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**What should be done to handle the situation? I do not want the application to force close in this situation.**

Comment: whats line 623 of .parse_MarqueeContent() thats where its coming from

Comment: @JRowan I konow that the line has this: Document doc = parser.getDomElement(marqueeContent); // getting DOM element I think when the marqueeContent is not getting any xml inside it, its giving the exception. How to handle it?

Comment: @Jaguar you are looking at the wrong place, please look into this class MyAsyncTask_marquee as this class is responsible for the marquee post request

Comment: put it all in if(marqueeContent != null) block

Comment: @JRowan that is fine I guess, but how should I handle the else part?

Comment: execute the Asynctask again, maybe after a certain time interval

Comment: or you cant execute a AsyncTask twice can you, im lost here

Comment: @JRowan any snippet for that if you please?